# Comparing two columns and matching values from seperate work sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

The goal of my project is to create an out of office program that will allow easy tracking and auditing of our Sharepoint site as it doesnt have a built in system to do.  I have no background in VBA, but I have done quite a bit of python.  That being said I've ran into my first issue.  I'm not sure how the syntax works, and what commands I should be using to get the results I want.  I.e. sheets vs worksheet vs worksheets.

I have a workbook, 1 sheet is Raw Data, in which I import data from a sharpoint site. It displays the following columns

Resource Name -- Absence Type -- ID -- Start Time -- End Time -- Created -- Modified by

The next sheet I have is tracking, it's called Tracking. On this page the user imputs Resource Names they want to track into Column A, and then the remainign columns are going to display the number of absences that name has so it will look something like

Resource Name -- Vacation -- Sick -- WFH

Clooney, George -- 2 -- 0 -- 7

A counter will run based on each instance that appears in raw data and adds the number to the counter based on the absence type from raw data.

I need a way to loop through Raw Data and look for the names that appear in the Tracking data.  If Possible I'd like to store them in a third worksheet jsut for testing purposes. I know the logic I need to use, but what I dont know is the syntax to refrence the pages together. Any insight on the best way to accomplish this?

**Question :**  I need to Search raw data for every instance Resource Name appears in it from the Tracking page and store into another worksheet.

Comment: You could do this with worksheet formulas such as `COUNTIFS()` - assuming you're on Excel2007+.

Comment: Thats how I planned to do the counts for absence type, but how do I refrence the names cross worksheets? and Sorry for nto including that I am in Excel 2007

Comment: To refernce another sheet you should do `worksheetName!cellRef` so to get cell A1 in Raw Data you would do `'Raw Data'!A1`

Comment: @Ff - you can select the relavant ranges while entering your formula: just switc htabs and select the required cells.

Comment: Thanks JonKelly and @TW, but Tim with this I dont think the Formula will work as the ranges change, currently I have 1600 rows, but if somebody else goes on vaction it will change. So what I want to do is for each Resource name in Tracking, loop through Raw Data and pull every instance out for that name.

Comment: Just use a much larger range in your formula than you currently have data for.  Or define dynamic named ranges: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use PivotTables (can be hard to search later) this is the way to do it with COUNTIFS.  This formula goes in the "Sick" column of Tracking in row 2 (assuming row 1 is headers).

`=COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!A:A,Tracking!A2,'Raw Data'!B:B,"Sick")`

It assumes that in Raw Data Name is in column A and AbsenceType is in Column B, but it doesn't matter how many records there are.

Comment: That helps a lot. Countifs is a lot more powerful than I thought. I want to upvote you but sadly I don't have 15 reputation. Also Can you tell me how I would be able to write the records it's counting into another worksheet? or what Formula I would use?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question (and it wasn't easy), you are dealing with a bunch of timesheet info. You seem to be trying to count the number of instances of different kinds of time off that people are taking - whether that be vacation, sick or working from home(WFH).

I've never heard someone's name referred to as a "Resource Name" lol.

You really don't need to use VBA for this problem - at least not anything that you can't just record  a macro for - it seems to be a rather simple problem that can you solve using a pivot table.

[image: Pivot Table Example]

If you want to you can set up a vlookup reference to this pivot table to create the little form that you seem to be trying to create. But really I think your better off just teaching whoever is going to be using this about pivot tables. Let me know if I misunderstood your question and I'll be happy to delete this post.

Comment: Resource Name is how the name of the employee is stored into SharePoint, it's the Unique Identifer, and the pivot table looks like a good idea, but the program is also going to handle when things are deleted from SharePoint. That means I will also have an Audit worksheet as well. The purpose of this is tracking and security as some emplyoees vacation has been deleted in the calendar and it's like they never took it in the first place. Also Ideally it's all going to be in vba because I'm an intern, and the goal is to make this all automated and as simple to use as can be.

Comment: But this does seem like a great idea and does provide a solution to my issue, however I need a VBA solution as it will help me with other issue with my project down the road. Thanks though!

Comment: Like I said, you could record a macro that creates the pivot table and then you could make a little vlookup form that looks up the person's name and their total for each time-off column. This is what excel was meant to do - using VBA is not going to make it any easier for the user. Even with a countif solution you would not need to use VBA. Are you familiar with how to record macros?

Comment: Not very, but I think this will work for this aspect of my program, however I'm going to later have to import more data in from the SharePoint site. Upon being imported into Excel I have to compare every ID from the imported data, to the data already in the workbook, if an ID is in the workbook, but not in the imported data, I have to add that record to an audit spreadsheet. The VBA solution for this question would be ver ysimliar to that as I'd once again be comparing data from two worksheets.  Do you know of a way to accomplish that with a macro as well?

Comment: Well, that is an legitimate problem but that is a different issue, so I would recommend you post a separate question for that issue - and give people a chance to answer that seperately. However, the answer would undoubtedly use countif or sumif or vlookup or some variation like that. You could use vlookup to reference a counter column to see if there is at least on instance of that name on the original sheet.

Comment: I was just trying to explain why I wanted to do it the way I am.  I like the idea of pivot tables and the solution you gave me, but I'm just looking down the road and I think it may cause me problems later in my process.